# Why can't I get my moderncv to compile? - unrecognized command (tex editor)

Tags: miktex, moderncv, windows

I have moved to windows 10 from arch linux. I am now attempting to use MiKTeX and TexStudio to alter an existing CV. I have added the package entitled `moderncv` within the MiKTeX Console. However when I open my existing `moderncv` CV to edit it in TexEditor, I have multiple compilation errors around `\cvline`; my compiler (MiKTeX) claims it doesn't recognise the command. Please help.

Comment: It might help if you post the log, especially if you're just getting the errors from your editor as many editors parses the log log file and some are not good at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your existing CV is a little bit old. Command `\cvline` is not longer used in current class `moderncv` 2.0.0, it uses now `\cvitem`.

With installing package `moderncv` via MiKTeX Console you got the current version 2.0.0 installed. Now you have to check the examples for `moderncv` 2.0.0 to use the correct new commands for layouting your cv.  Be aware that several commands changed their names, you have to correct all of them. If you can not do that by your own, copy your cv to file `mwe.tex`, delete your personal informations from your new file and post it in your question. Then I can compile it and tell you the incorrect commands used ...

Without seeing your cv tex code I can not help you more ...

Comment: perfect. Can you please tell me what has replaced \moderncvtheme

Comment: @HellishHeat Use the two new commands `\moderncvstyle{casual}` and `\moderncvcolor{blue}` ... Use your option values instead ``casual` and `blue` ...